# Appcelerator Changing image according to platform

Tags: ipad, appcelerator

I'm developing an app on Titanium.
Now I'm trying to change the image of my app according to its platform, mobile or tablet.
What am I doing wrong?

```
"#header[platform=ios formFactor=handheld]" :{
    image:"/images/header.png"
}
"#header[platform=ios formFactor=tablet]" :{
    image:"/images/header-ipad.png"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the control you are trying to style set as id='header'?  I tested this on IOS with styling a view, but I didn't attempt to use images.  I initially thought the missing comma between the styles could be the issue, but that doesn't stop my example project from working.

Comment: If you rename iamge as header~ipad.png it is automatically picked by iPad and iPhone picks header.png. No need to specify it seperately in tss.